# iOS error message tooltip

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to show error message as a tooltip in iOS 8 but i don't know how to do it. What I want is something similar to the one shown in below image (I'm referring to the tooltip with messages Select and Select All):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great collection of libraries which already target your problem.
For example have a look at: [AMPopTip](https://github.com/andreamazz/AMPopTip).

Then you could show the popover like:

```
self.popTip = [AMPopTip popTip];
[self.popTip showText:errorMessage direction:AMPopTipDirectionUp maxWidth:200 inView:self.view fromFrame:textField.frame];
```

and hide it:

```
[self.popTip hide];
```

Have a look at the github repo there are more examples for customizing this control.

You can find more which might suit your needs better here: [cocoacontrols.com](http://cocoacontrols.com)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and wrote my own custom tooltip.

You can init with your custom view (i assume you write some delegations to detect actions within.) and present from anywhere.

Maybe not the best replacement of UIPopoverController but still works great. And a lifesaver for iPhone. Also highly customisable.

https://github.com/akeara/AKETooltip

Hope this helps.